# Change color of progress bar programmatically

Tags: android, colors, progress-bar, programmatically-created

I want to change the colors of a `ProgressBar` in Android only programmatically.
My problem is, how can I set a different color for the progress and another color for the "to fill" - part of the progress bar

Example:

- Progress should be green
- Last part should be red

[image: it should look like this]

Comment: have a look at this http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possibility to do that atm.
You have to develop your own custom view for achieving this.

Create a custom view, extending a Layout, and use the layout for your background of the progress bar. Add another view (starting with 0dp width) for your growing progress.

Add a public method for setting the current progress and adjust the width of the progress view.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply a custom Style to a Progressbar with the official API.

You might be able to do it using reflection though.
A Progressbar has a private field `mProgressTintInfo` which has following fields: `mProgressTintList`and `mProgressBackgroundTintList`, which are ColorStateLists and `mHasProgressTint` and `mHasProgressBackgroundTint`, which are booleans.

I've never tried this myself, it might not work at all or only work on specific API levels / devices.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english, i speak spanish
yo can implement you own progressbar, and override the method "ondraw" and uses 2 filled rectangles and a 2 filled circles with yours own colors.

again, super sorry for my english,..